# How can I write a 2D MATLAB function which smoothes an image via a 2D Gaussian Cumulative Function that where its means are is determined by the user?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering, smoothing, probability-distribution

How can I write a 2D gaussian cumulative matlab function that gets applied to an input 2D binary image. The mean of the gaussian cumulative is on a particular selected curved line which will be given as an input.
So the inputs of the function is:

1. The main 2D binary image.
2. A 2D binary matrix with the same size as the main 2D binary image which is 1 where the 2D gaussian cumulative function’s means should be, and 0 everywhere else.
3. The standard deviation of the 2D Gaussian cumulative function

And the output is the smoothed form of the main 2D binary image

I have tried this code but its all wrong:

```
function [smoothed_image] = gaussian_cumulative_2D(binary_image, mean_loop, std_dev)

% Create a meshgrid for the x and y coordinates
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:size(binary_image,2), 1:size(binary_image,1));

% Calculate the distance from each point to the mean loop
distance = sqrt((x-mean_loop(1)).^2 + (y-mean_loop(2)).^2);

% Calculate the gaussian cumulative function
gaussian_cumulative = 0.5*(1 + erf(distance/(std_dev*sqrt(2))));

% Apply the gaussian cumulative function to the binary image
smoothed_image = binary_image.*gaussian_cumulative;

end
```

Comment: What is a “2D Gaussian cumulative function”? Is this the 2D integral of a 2D Gaussian? Or is it something else? What you compute as `gaussian_cumulative` is the 1D integral of a 1D Gaussian. What is “apply” in this context? You are multiplying the image by the `gaussian_cumulative` map you created. Maybe you need to compute a convolution? To smooth an image you’d convolve it with a smoothing kernel, such as a Gaussian. A convolution with an error function would be… uncommon.